# CakePHP 2.x hasMany that belongsTo another table

Tags: cakephp, relationships

I have my base Model **Affiliate** that hasMany **AffiliatePayout** and these **AffiliatePayouts** belongTo a **Payout**. Now I'm doing a `$this->Affiliate->find('all', array())` and its returning an array of **AffiliatePayouts** but I would also like to get the **Payout** that belongsTo the **AffiliatePayout** returned along with the results. I've racked my brain most of the day trying to figure this out and can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this -> Affiliate -> find('all', array('contain' => 'Payout'))
```

Here you have more info about Containable Behavior

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: The **Affiliate** does not belongTo **Payout** only the **AffiliatePayout** belongsTo **Payout**

Comment: Ok then maybe try to up recursive level 
`$this -> Affiliate -> find('all', array('recursive' => 2))`
More info about [recursive property](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @Jacek B Budzynski I did `$this->Affiliate->find('all', array('contain' => array('AffiliatePayout' => array('Payout')));` I was able to get it to work. My use case is a bit more advanced that what is posted but this fixed my issue. Thank you @Jacek